# How do I let other users embed videos onto my site?

Tags: html, youtube-api, embed

I'm a web developer with limited knowledge in programming. So basically, I have a website that allows a user to login and have their own profile page and everything. One of the main features is that the user can take a video that they made on YouTube, and then embed it onto their page where others can view it. However, I have no idea how to do it, or if it is actually possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't users just paste the video's embed code, or is this something different?

Comment: If the users are copying and pasting, then they would have to edit the source code and everything. What I'm trying to accomplish is for them to provide a link to their video, and then for the server to somehow embed that onto their personal page.

Answer (score 2):

Embedded videos are actually just an IFrame to a special YouTube URL that puts the video fullpage. So, if you put an IFrame using that URL you get the video as a box that has the full size of the IFrame.

The embedding URL is `https://www.youtube.com/embed/[ID]` where `[ID]` is the video ID (you can find the video ID at the end of any URL; as an example, in `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ` the video ID is `dQw4w9WgXcQ`).

Put that embed URL in an IFrame and you are ready to go. As an example, the following code is taken from the *Embed video* section that appears below YouTube videos.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[VIDEO ID]"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The [Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) will provide you more help and extra parameters. For instance, you can make the video autoplay by adding `?autoplay=1` at the end of the embed URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro but I think this is how it would work in pseudo code.

When a user logs in they will have to connect your website with their youtube accounts (somehow).

Then you would get the URLS to each of their videos into a db.

You can then let the user select a video to upload. When they choose one, all you do is embed the video using html and replace the URL with Youtube's URL link.

Would this work?

Comment: That's actually pretty interesting. I never though of it that way. However, this is obviously a little theoretical. Both of us aren't pros, so I have no idea if it would work. But the part about connecting the website to YouTube is pretty neat.